# Paste in a specific range

Tags: vba

[image]

Look the code below:

```
 With Worksheets("L.NAM.M")
        With .Cells.Find(What:="forecast_quarter", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
            xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
            xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            .Parent.Range(.Offset(1), .Parent.Cells(Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp)).Copy _
            Destination:=Worksheets("NewForecast").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End With
    End With

With Worksheets("L.EMEA.O")
    With .Cells.Find(What:="forecast_quarter", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        .Parent.Range(.Offset(1), .Parent.Cells(Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("NewForecast").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End With
End With


      'Record Source

        With Worksheets("L.EMEO.O")
        With .Cells.Find(What:="Record Source", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
            xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
            xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            .Parent.Range(.Offset(1), .Parent.Cells(Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("NewForecast").Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End With
    End With
```

What I am doing here..I am getting data forecast_quarter of those two spreadsheets and pasting below the header of a new spreadsheet. So, it is finding the lastrow with data and pasting below. The trick part comes when look for Record Source from "L.EMEA.O", as the "L.NAM.M" does not have any data for column L, it messes up when I paste the L.EMEA.O data, as it does not align with the L.EMEA.O but with L.NAM.O. What I would like is to paste aligned the row of where it pasted the forecast_quarter for L.EMEA.O.

Any ideas? I attache a photo

[image]

In this case it pasted in the K114,if i run the other piece, I want to paste in the same not in the N110, but N114.

Comment: I don't have a full picture of what you're trying to do or what the problem is at all. More images would be helpful. It sounds like a very easy problem to solve.

Comment: Hi! thanks for answering! Sorry if i am not that clear..But I am attaching a new picture.
In the picture you can see that Forecast_Quarter from one sheet  goes until A10(Whatever), and Record Source until A8. The second sheet the forecast_quarter starts at A11(the first blank cell) and goes to A23. As my formula is like, find the first blank cell and paste, my record source will start at B9, because this is where is the first blank, what I want is to start at the same row of the my second sheet forecast quarter(Wherever), in this case B11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

store the row index used for "L.EMEA.O" and use it for "L.EMEO.O" as well:

```
   With Worksheets("L.NAM.M")
           With .Cells.Find(What:="forecast_quarter", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
               xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
               xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
               .Parent.Range(.Offset(1), .Parent.Cells(Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp)).Copy _
               Destination:=Worksheets("NewForecast").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
           End With
       End With

    Dim L_EMEA_ORow As Long '<--| variable to hold "forecast_quarter" sheet column "K" row index where to start pasting "L.EMEA.O" sheet data from
    With Worksheets("L.EMEA.O")
       With .Cells.Find(What:="forecast_quarter", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
           xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
           xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
           L_EMEA_ORow = Worksheets("NewForecast").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row '<--| store relevant row index where to start pasting data from
           .Parent.Range(.Offset(1), .Parent.Cells(Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("NewForecast").Range("K" & L_EMEA_ORow) '<--| use relevant row index
       End With
    End With


    'Record Source

    With Worksheets("L.EMEO.O")
        With .Cells.Find(What:="Record Source", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
            xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
            xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            .Parent.Range(.Offset(1), .Parent.Cells(Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("NewForecast").Range("N" & L_EMEA_ORow) '<--| use same relevant row index calculated above
        End With
    End With
```

Comment: you are the best, really. Thank you again! so good to see how people help here!

Comment: You are welcome. While I, sadly, am not the best. But glad to be of help.